# How to force UIC to generate ui_mainwindow.h in the source directory using cmake

Tags: qt, cmake, catkin

UIC successfully creates the ui_mainwindow.h file but it stores it in the build directory. This causes the compile time error 'ui_mainwindow.h: No such file or directory found'.

If I add the full path to the ui_mainwindow.h file in the build directory, cmake (catkin_make) successfully builds the project. Obviously I'd like to avoid using the absolute path to a header file in my source code.

The relevant parts of my CMakeLists:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core )
add_executable(monitor src/mainwindow.cpp src/main.cpp src/mainwindow.ui)
qt5_use_modules(monitor Widgets)

target_link_libraries(monitor Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

How do I force UIC to build the ui_mainwindow.h file in my source directory. Or how do I include the cmake build directory in my CMakeLists.txt

I've tried

```
qt5_wrap_ui (monitor_UI src/mainwindow.ui OPTIONS -o 'ui_mainwindow.h')
add_executable(monitor src/mainwindow.cpp src/main.cpp ${monitor_UI})
```

with no success.

Comment: Note that if you put generated files in source directory, it's kinda undermines the whole point of having a separate build dir. Perhaps you should do the "normal" thing and use include paths instead of making such an unusual build configuration.

Comment: @hyde I'd be ok with adding the build directory in the include path. Is there a cmake variable that points to this build directory, or would i have to use something like `../../.. .. /build`?

Comment: @hyde Thanks for the tip. I used ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} in the includepath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on hyde's comment, I simply added the build directory in the includepaths using

```
include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
)
```

which solved my problem.

Comment: better to use
```cmake
target_include_directories(monitor PRIVATE
   "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}>"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR.html#prop_tgt:AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR) CMake variable specifies *where* `AUTOUIC` should generate files. If you want the generated files to be placed in your current source directory, you can set it to [`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html):

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

An additional note from the CMake-Qt [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-qt.7.html#autouic) for using `AUTOUIC` with the `AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR` variable:

> The generated `ui_*.h` files are placed in the `<AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR>/include` directory which is automatically added to the target’s `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`.

So, you should **not** have to explicitly list the directory containing the generated headers in an `include_directories()` command.

Comment: I tried this but it still generates the header file in the build directory

Comment: Did you try running CMake from *scratch*? By deleting the build folder, or removing the CMakeCache.txt file?

Comment: @ShawnMathew I agree that the generated headers should be placed somewhere in your *binary* directories, but you can still use `AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR` to control where. I expanded my answer to explain why `include_directories()` should not be necessary when using this approach. Glad you got it working though!

Comment: I deleted the build directory and ran cmake (catkin_make) again with no success. I don't see a new include directory anywhere and I still get the same error.